# Calling a constructor from another class

Tags: c#, oop

I have the following constructors in a class called `BaseRobot`:

```
public BaseRobot(int aId)
{
    mId = aId;
    mHome.X = 0;
    mHome = new Point(0, 0);
    mPosition = mHome;
}

public BaseRobot(int aId, int aX, int aY)
{
    mId = aId;
    mHome = new Point(aX, aY);
    mPosition = mHome;
}
```

How do I call the `BaseRobot` constructor in another class?

Comment: From a derived class? Or from a separate class altogether?

Comment: In the first constructor, you are setting `mHome.X` before you set `mHome`.

Comment: Its for a separate class

Answer (score 8):

```
var robot = new BaseRobot(7); //calls the first constructor
var robot2 = new BaseRobot(7, 8, 9); //calls the second
```

if you are creating a derived class

```
public class FancyRobot : BaseRobot
{
   public FancyRobot() : base(7, 8, 9) 
   { // calls the 2nd constructor on the base class
      Console.WriteLine("Created a fancy robot with defaults");
   }
}

//this calls the FancyRobot default constructor, which in-turn calls the BaseRobot constructor
var fancy = new FancyRobot();
```

You never call a constructor directly, the code only executes when the object is instantiated. If you want to set properties on an object from another class, you can create public properties or methods that set a classes member variables.

```
public class AnotherRobotType
{
    public string Model {get;set;} // public property
    private int _make; // private property
    public AnotherRobotType() {
    }

    /* these are methods that set the object's internal state
    this is a contrived example, b/c in reality you would use a auto-property (like Model) for this */
    public int getMake() { return _make; }
    public void setMake(int val) { _make = val; } 
}

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       // setting object properties from another class
       var robot = new AnotherRobotType();
       robot.Model = "bender";
       robot.setMake(1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Constructors are called when you newly create an instance of the class. Example,

```
BaseRobot _robot = new BaseRobot(1);
```

which calls the constructor that accepts int parameter.